# Saving a Word document and setting DisplayAlerts to disable prompt to save

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` or `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to avoid a Word popup message just before saving a Word document.

> The document being saved contains track changes Continue with save?

```
Private Sub CreateReportButton_Click()
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim objDocB As Word.Document
    Dim objDocC As Word.Document
    
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolderA As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderB As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFolderC As Scripting.Folder
    
    Dim colFilesA As Scripting.Files
    Dim objFileA As Scripting.File
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolderA = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with the original documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderB = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder with revised documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    Set objFolderC = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder("Choose the folder for the comparisons documents", ThisDocument.Path))
    
    Set colFilesA = objFolderA.Files
    
    For Each objFileA In colFilesA
    If objFileA.Name Like "*.docx" Then
        Set objDocA = Documents.Open(objFolderA.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocB = Documents.Open(objFolderB.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name)
        Set objDocC = Application.CompareDocuments( _
            OriginalDocument:=objDocA, _
            RevisedDocument:=objDocB, _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationNew)
        objDocA.Close
        objDocB.Close
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        'Turn off DisplayAlerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        
        objDocC.SaveAs FileName:=objFolderC.Path & "\" & objFileA.Name
        objDocC.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Next objFileA
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error (MS Word 2016). Error stems from this process: `CompareDocuments`. Check results of comparison, if documents are big you could need some more time before you close document.

Comment: My script is working under Word 2013 even if the files are big (the only way that the both versions of the same document must to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it depends on the version of office, In 2013 it's necessary to go to the Trust Center area of the application (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options) and uncheck the option "Warm before printing, saving or sending a file that contains tracked changes or comments". After doing that files are saved with any message of Word

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain those settings, then for the purposes of your code you could use something along the lines of:

```
Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = False
ActiveDocument.Save
Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = True
```

or, for more flexibility with systems that may not be using that setting:

```
Dim bWarn as Boolean
bWarn = Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup
Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = False
ActiveDocument.Save
Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = bWarn
```